# How to Implement (via typing) two addresses (origin and destination), and place them as markers on a map (googlemaps api)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm new to Android and trying to place in my app **two textfields in which i would be able to type addresses** (*origin and destination*) and with a **button click, these addresses will display as points in the map**.

I was able to complete the first part, meaning that in the first textfield, i'm able to type my origin address, and then by clicking the Button, the point appears in the map. 
My problem is that when i'm typing the "destination address", either my app crushes, or nothing happens (meaning no new point appears in the map).

This is my "MapsActivity" code so far

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public void onSearch(View view)
{
    EditText location_tf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtedit);
    String location =location_tf.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressesList = null ;
    if (location != null || !location.equals(""))
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressesList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location , 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        LinkedHashMap addressList;
        Address address = addressesList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude() , address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng ));

    }

    EditText location_tf1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtedit2);
    String location1 =location_tf1.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressesList1 = null ;
    if (location != null || !location.equals(""))
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressesList1 = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location , 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        LinkedHashMap addressList;
        Address address = addressesList1.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude() , address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker1"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng ));

    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Areios Pagos Athens and move the camera
    LatLng white_tower = new LatLng(40.626459, 22.948419);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(white_tower).title("Marker in white tower"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(white_tower));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

and this is my "Activity_maps.xml" file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtedit"
    android:text="Origin address!"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="#a6a5a5"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtedit2"
    android:text="Destination address!"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="#a6a5a5"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Find addresses"
    android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="onSearch" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.elesar.googleaddresssearch.MapsActivity" />
```

So, when i'm trying to run my application, type an address in the first "origin addresss" and hit the button "Find addresses", the marker appears on the map! On the other hand, when i'm typing an address in "destination address" nothing happens.Any suggestions?????
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see your code for `txtedit2` and only `EditText location_tf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtedit);`. Can you show your code on how you are calling the "destination address"?

Comment: @abielita, thanx for your response. The reason you don't see my code for txtedit2, because i delete it thinking it was complete wrong (I used pretty much the code for txtedit with some name changes). I am pretty sure that it doesn't work like this,that's why i delete it, and needed some help. I now added it, in my "posted" code. 
Thanx again!